# Facebook Registration Plugin Throwing Error

Tags: facebook, plugins, registration

Our site have integrated registration and login through facebook using facebook regsitration plugin as described in url https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/v1.0.

Recently 3 months back we upgraded Facebook API to version 2.2 but kept our registration plugin to as described in above url and it worked well. But today we noticed that facebook registration plugin control is not working. It is throwing following error

> Unable to load the registration form. You may have previously blocked
>
> this app on Facebook. Go to your Facebook privacy settings to unblock
>
> this app. (Error: 404)

We did some research and find the url https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/v2.2 which states that this registration plugin control will stop working after 30th July 2015. But not sure why it has stopped working before that day.

Can any one please let us know why this error is coming? And also what is the resolution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/v1.0):

> The Registration Plugin is deprecated and will be removed on April 30,
>   2015. You should not integrate this plugin into new apps. If you're using this plugin, you should replace it with Facebook Login before
>   April 30, 2015

Even if this were a bug it is highly unlikely that it will be looked into since it is deprecated.

The only resolution is to migrate to [Facebook Login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/v2.4) as suggested in the warning message.